# Doob's inequalities: Going from discrete to continuous

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-analysis

After having read about Doob's inequalities in discrete time, I am trying to understand the move to continuous time. I know that the Martingale regularization theorem tells me that there is (under the usual hypotheses) a càdlàg version of my martingale. I also know that it can be shown that the sample paths of càdlàg processes only have countably many discontinuities. What I fail to understand so far, is how this comes into play in moving from discrete to continuous.

Specifically I'm looking at a proof of Doob's maximal inequality from Alan Sola's Part III Probability notes at Cambridge (unfortunately he seems to have moved and the pdf isn't online anymore). So let's assume that $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a càdlàg martingale and let $\lambda\geq 0$. Then he considers the usual dyadic discretization of the interval $[0,t]$:

$$ D_n = \left\{kt2^{-n}:k=0,...,2^n\right\}$$
and defines discrete martingales $X^n$ and filtrations $\mathcal{F}^{n}$ by setting (for $k=0,\ldots,2^n$)

$$X^n_k=X_{\dfrac{kt}{2^n}}$$
$$\mathcal{F}^n_k=\mathcal{F}_{\dfrac{kt}{2^n}}$$

Then the usual maximal inequality in discrete time gives me that 
$$\lambda P\left(\max_{k\leq 2^n}|X^n_k| >\lambda\right)\leq E|X_t|$$

Next, we define for $n=1,2,\ldots$

$$A_n=\left\{\sup_{s\in D_n}|X_s| > \lambda\right\}$$

and note that these events are increasing in $n$, that is $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$.

*The next step is the one I don't understand*: Because $X$ càdlàg,

$$ \left\{\sup_{s\leq t}|X_s| > \lambda \right\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$$

Could someone please point me in a direction or explain to me how cadlag comes into play here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\sup_{s<t} |X_s|> \lambda$ therefore, there is an $t^*\in [0,t)$ with $|X(t^*)|> \lambda$ or $|X(t)|> \lambda$.

$\{|X(t)| > \lambda\} \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$

If there is an $t^*\in [0,t)$ with $|X(t^*)|> \lambda$ then there is a sequence a dyadic $s_n = \frac{\lfloor{2^n t}\rfloor + 1}{2^n} \in D_n$ $s_n \downarrow t^*$  and right continuity gives us that there is $n \in \Bbb{N}$ for which $|X(s_n)|> \lambda$ and therefore

$\{\exists t^* \in [0,t) ,|X(t^*)|> \lambda\} \subset \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$

So we can conclude that
$$ \bigg\{\sup_{s\leq t}|X_s| > \lambda\bigg\} \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$$

the other inclusion $$ \bigg\{\sup_{s\leq t}|X_s| > \lambda\bigg\} \supset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n $$

Follows from the fact that

$$\bigg\{\sup_{s\leq t}|X_s| > \lambda\bigg\} \supset  A_n  \quad \forall n$$

Comment: Just to clarify whether I have understood: That the LHS is contained in the RHS is easy because $A_n$ lies in the LHS and so does their (infinite) union. To show that the LHS is contained in the RHS, I split it up into 'just before t' and 'at t'. Now the 'at t' part is clear. The second part however is not entirely clear yet. So in your example do we approximate the $t^*$ by a sequence of dyadic $s_n \in D_n$? So essentially we are using the right continuity of X?

Comment: Yes that is right. we  approximate the $t^∗$ by a sequence of dyadic $s_n\inD_n$ using the right continuity of X.

Comment: Ok, I get it! I only wonder why they placed so much emphasis on the fact that the number of discontinuities is countable if we don't use it here?