# Doob's Maximal Inequality Continuous Time

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

I am given the following proof of this result, but part of it is completely unclear to me:

Suppose $M$ is a nonnegative, progressively measurable, right continuous martingale.  Then $P(\text{sup}_{s \leq t} M_s \ge c) \leq E(M_0)/c$

**Proof:**

Define $M_t^* = \text{sup}_{s \leq t}M_s$ and $\tau_c \equiv \text{inf}\{t: M_t^* \ge c\}$

Then clearly we have $\{\tau_c \leq t\} = \{M_t^* \ge c\}$

$(**)$ Now the proof claims that $M_{\tau_c} \ge c$ on the set $\{\tau_c \leq t\}$.  I do not understand this.

From this point, the proof proceeds easily, as assuming $(**)$ is true we have $$P(M_t^* \ge c) = P(\tau_c \leq t) \leq \frac{1}{c}E(M_{\tau_c \wedge t} 1(\tau_c \leq t)) \leq \frac{1}{c}E(M_{\tau_c \wedge t}) = \frac{E(M_0)}{c}$$

since $\tau_c \wedge t$ is a bounded stopping time.

The reason I don't understand why $(**)$ is true is because I see clearly how $M_s^* < c$ for all $s < \tau_c$ just from the definition of $\tau_c$.  I can show that $M_t^*$ is right continuous, so that (assuming $\tau_c(\omega)$ is finite) we have $M_{\tau_c}^* \ge c$. However, I do not believe that this necessarily implies $M_{\tau_c} \ge c$, because I cannot produce a contradiction from assuming $M_{\tau_c} < c$.

Any help or alternative proof strategies would be massively appreciated because I don't at all see how this works.  Please help!

Comment: I agree that it is not reasonable to expect that $M_{\tau_c} \geq c$. An alternative strategy is to prove the inequality first for (time)discrete martingales and extend it using an approximation.

Comment: In that case I would have to change $P(M_t^* \ge c)$ to $P(M_t^* > c)$ as in the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426890/doobs-inequalities-going-from-discrete-to-continuous?rq=1), right?  This is because the supremum may be $= \lambda$ (in their notation) even if $|X_s| < \lambda \forall s$

Comment: Yes, that's correct but it's not so much of a problem. Once you have shown the estimate for $P(M_t^*>c)$, you can use the continuity of the measure to get the estimate for $P(M_t^* \geq c)$. Just note that $$P(M_t^* \geq c) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(M_t^*>c-1/n)\leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{c-1/n} E(M_0) = \frac{E(M_0)}{c}.$$

Comment: This is awesome; thank you so much!